# Change Post meta based on user role

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, user-roles, post-meta

I cannot find a solution to this WordPress problem: I have multiple user roles that all can submit front end posts that were created with custom post types. I would like to change the user's submitted post's taxonomy based on the upgraded/downgraded user role. In example, the user has level "2" the assigned taxonomy to his/her posts is "special". Once the plan expires I would like to have the user's post's taxonomy changed to "featured".

Hope to receive some help here.

Comment: Demo url? And what you tried

Comment: It is installed on a local machine but I fear it would not help anyway to see the site from the frontend. Here is a more detailed step by step process of what I did:

I created a custom post type and assigned multiple ACF's to it. 
I registered 6 (S, S+, M, M+, L, L+) user roles in total.
Each user role is allowed to publish X frontend posts. 
Now I want to give each user the ability to upgrade their account to the "+" user role.

Comment: This user role would then change the taxonomy of their so far published posts as well as all future published posts from "special" to "featured" for the time that their "+" account is active. After the expiration the taxonomy changes back to "featured". The reason why I want to achieve this is to later on highlights the "special" taxonomy posts as well as restrict access for certain users to this content.